# Python List of Strings created from a list of one string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say you have a list `['dogs, cats']`. How can one turn that into `['dogs', 'cats']` for arbitrary number of `['x, y, z']`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "list of unique substrings"?  Your example isn't making it clear to me - maybe provide another example?  Do you just want to split any string of the form 'a, b, c, ..., n' into ['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'n']?

Comment: Does your first list only have one element or can there be multiple elements that are comma separated strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just split the first element on `', '`:

```
>>> ['dogs, cats'][0].split(', ')
['dogs', 'cats']
>>>
>>> ['x, y, z'][0].split(', ')
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

If you can have multiple comma separated string in your list, then you can use list comprehension:

```
>>> li = ['x, y, z', 'dogs, cats']
>>> 
>>> li2 = [elem.split(', ') for elem in li]
>>> [v for val in li2 for v in val]
['x', 'y', 'z', 'dogs', 'cats']
```

Or using `sum()` over list comprehension:

```
>>> li = ['x, y, z', 'dogs, cats']
>>>
>>> sum([elem.split(', ') for elem in li], [])
['x', 'y', 'z', 'dogs', 'cats']
```

And finally [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(elem.split(', ') for elem in li))
['x', 'y', 'z', 'dogs', 'cats']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split(', ') which gives you the List

list = ['dogs, cats', 'x, y, z']

finalList = []

for key in list:
    finalList.extend(key.split(', '))

you will get
['x', 'y', 'z', 'dogs', 'cats']